# sort a custom field base on the date or anything

Tags: custom-field

I'm working on a project right now and I'm facing an issue that is about to freak me out.

Basically I had to display information of some courses, in order to do so, I create a custom field called "CourseInfo", that array includes, date, place, and a link to sign in.

So the user create that custom field as long as he needs, cause courses can be infinites, however I need to order the output based on the course date and not based on the last custom field created.

Since the course date includes month and the year, is there a change to order it basd on the date?

I would appreciate any help!

Thanks!

UPDATE****** ------------------------------------------

Basically I'm using this code, maybe it will help

```
 <?php $limit = 1; $courses = array_reverse($courses); foreach ($courses as $course) {
                            $course = nl2br($course);
                            list($date,$city,$link) = explode('<br />',$course);

 echo "<ul>";
 echo "<li>$date</li>";
 echo "<li>$city</li>";
 echo "<li><a href='$link'>Inschrijven</a></li>";
 echo "</ul>";

 }  ?>
```

And the page is http://www.otoacademie.nl/dev/rijinstructeur-auto-b/

Notice there is not order.

UPDATE=====================================================
update dates format

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you give us an example of the data contained in `$courses`?

Comment: sure, I'm updating the post with a ss of the custom fields =)

Comment: can you do a `echo "<pre>" . print_r($courses, true) . "</pre>"` and post that output? I'd like to see how the data is actually represented in the array.

Comment: I just set it in http://www.otoacademie.nl/dev/rijinstructeur-auto-b/  Just click  "Alle opleidingsdata en locaties zien" and you will see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Multiline is not an array *(rant)*
2. You need to use standard dates for this to work **DD/MM/YYYY** *(first row)*
3. Use the PHP function [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the fields
4. Use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert that date to a timestamp and [date_i18n()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) to output it

If you need an actual example, change the date formats to what I've shown you above, update the screenshot and I'll give you the code. First line must be DD/MM/YYYY.

### THE CODE

```
// Demo set (replace with you custom fields)
$courses = array(
    '27/10/2011<br />'. // Date
        'Amsterdam<br />'. // City
            'http://www.google.com/', // Link
    '19/10/2011<br />'. // Date
        'Amsterdam<br />'. // City
            'http://www.google.com/', // Link
    '17/01/2011<br />'. // Date
        'Amsterdam<br />'. // City
            'http://www.google.com/', // Link
);
// Convert the courses to objects and translate the dates
$sorted_courses = array(); // Holds objects for sorting
foreach($courses as $course){
    $course = nl2br($course);
    // Replace <br /> with \r\n
    $course = preg_replace('~<br[\s]*/[\s]*>~i', PHP_EOL, $course);
    // Split by \r\n and trim each entry
    list($date, $city, $link) = array_map('trim', preg_split('~[\r\n]+~', $course));
    // Validate the date format [ :) ]
    if(!preg_match('~^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$~', $date, $slices)) continue;
    // Extract date elenents
    list($match, $day, $month, $year) = $slices;
    // And now create the object
    $sorted_courses[] = (object)array(
        'time'  => $time = mktime(1, 1, 1, $month, $day, $year),
        'date'  => $date = date_i18n('d F Y', $time),
        'city'  => $city,
        'link'  => $link,
    );
}
// Sort elements ascending (using callback)
usort($sorted_courses, function($item1, $item2){
    // Compare the timestamps and sort ascending
    return $item1->time > $item2->time;
});
// Got through the sorted courses and display them
foreach($sorted_courses as $sorted_course){
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>{$sorted_course->date}</li>";
        echo "<li>{$sorted_course->city}</li>";
        echo "<li><a href='{$sorted_course->link}'>Inschrijven</a></li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: just update it :) hope u can help me! thanks a ton!

Comment: Check it out :) Have fun!